# How do I manage to display in browser my React production build by using Spring Boot web server?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

> I want to browse my React pages in the browser. As a web server I use Spring 
>   Boot. The web server controller looks like this:

```
package com.steinko.reactspringboottutorial.webserver;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;



@Controller
public class HomeController {
     private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/" )
    String index(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("Request Mapping");
        log.info(request.toString());
        return "index";
    }

}
```

> My react production build file is called from the index.html fiel
>   I the /src/main/resources/templates/index.html files  contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Todo fronend</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{../../static/build/static/js/main.3a7ae2a8.chunk.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

> The react production build file is placed in  >src/main/static/build/static/js/main.3a7ae2a8.chunk.js
>   Build this program with Gradel. The build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE")
    }
}
plugins { 
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.3.1"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.steinko.reactspringboottutorial.webserver'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
       srcDirs = [ 
                   'src/main/resources',
                   'src/main/static'
                ]
    }
  }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR1")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}



dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}


node {
    /* gradle-node-plugin configuration
       https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md
       Task name pattern:
       ./gradlew npm_<command> Executes an NPM command.
    */
    // Version of node to use.
    version = '10.16.0'
    // Version of npm to use.
    npmVersion = '6.9.0'
    // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
    // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
    download = false
}
```

> After I have started the program with the command with the $gradle bootRun
>   and entered a localhost:8080 in the browser then the browser display a blank page
>   I get the following error message in the console window : 
>   GET http://localhost:8080/static/build/static/js/main.3a7ae2a8.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   In the browser the index.html look looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Todo fronend</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../static/build/static/js/main.3a7ae2a8.chunk.js"></script> </head> <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

</body> </html>
```

> How do I manage to display the React components in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

> I have found the solution
>   I have to move the build/static/js/ from src/main/static/build/static/js/ to >/src/main/resources/static/build/static/js
>   Then I had to compy the  src/main/javascript/public/index.html to >src/main/resources/templates/index.html
>   and I had to edit the loading of the build files to

```
<script th:src="@{build/static/js/2.f61826be.chunk.js}" type = "text/JavaScript"></script>
            <script th:src="@{build/static/js/main.3a7ae2a8.chunk.js}" type = "text/JavaScript"></script>
```